# Same Origin Policy Iframe Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, same-origin-policy

Due to the Same Orgin Policy in JavasSript we cannot access a second domain.

Is it possible to have two independent frames (e.g. Iframes) that load from different servers. 
Where each frame should only access his own html and server.
What do you think?

I had some error messages but I think it is only because one javascript tries to access the _top window.

So I want to know if it is possible to have two independent frames from different servers executing JavaScript and sending Ajax requests to their own servers.

And no: This is not a dublicate question. Since the other discussion is not about the frame solution.

Comment: Yes it's possible. They just cannot interact with each other.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know why this post has a down vote. Because it is a conceptual question? As I said I have already tried something which lead to errors. So I just want to know if it is even possible. Thank you @ahren.

Comment: Probably because it's a question that could be solved simply by trying it out... using a JSFiddle or the like.

Comment: Downvoting beginner question seems to be the new trend at SOF :( +1 from me

Comment: Why not document things instead of trying out each time? I thought this question was of general interest. And as you just proofed it was easy to answer for an expert.

Comment: Thank you groth. I would not say that dealing with frames is a beginner topic, since frames are really out of fashion (I know that iframes are newer). So I only use them if I have to. But this is not constructive anyway. The answer is clear to me now.